# Vertically align text in the table cell with modified arraystretch

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I have created simple table which purposefully has all cells, except first row and first column, blank.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\linespread{1.2}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{sideways}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 & Column 9 & Column 10 & Column 11 \\
\hline
Row 2 & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Row 3 & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Row 4 & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Row 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
Row 6 & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{sideways}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I have made three important changes: `\linespread{1.2}` for linespacing for the rest of the document (not relevant for MWE), `\def\arraystretch{1.5}` for vertical padding inside cells and `\setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}` for horizontal padding inside cells.

I want to have text in the cells to be centered both vertically and horizontally. Without those three commands above, it seems to happen. However, once I add those three commands for better presentation, they seem to move text in the cells below vertical center. Examples:

[image]
[image]

**Is there any way to keep those spacing/padding adjustments, but at the same time make text in the cell centered both vertically and horizontally**? Also, why code of MWE creates PDF with two pages, instead of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions for vertical centring of cell contents:

- The `makecell` package has commands for vertical padding of cell: `\setcellgapes` to define a value for the padding (in preamble), and `\makegapedcells` to use is in a given environment.
- The `cellspace` package works differently: it defines *minimal* vertical spacings between a cell and the above and below cells: `\cellspacetoplimit` and `cellspacebottomlimit`. You have to prefix the corresponding column specifier with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use the `siunitx` package).

Here is a code for both ways:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\setcellgapes{7.5pt}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{7.5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{7.5pt}
\linespread{1.2}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{sideways}
  \bgroup
  \makegapedcells
  \setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{11}{c|}}
    \multicolumn{11}{l}{\texttt{With makecell: }}\\[2ex]
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 & Column 9 & Column 10 & Column 11 \\
    \hline
    Row 2 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 3 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 4 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 6 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \egroup
\end{sideways}
\hskip1cm
\begin{sideways}
  \bgroup
  \setlength\tabcolsep{10pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{11}{Sc|}}
    \multicolumn{11}{c}{\texttt{With cellspace: }}\\[2ex]
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 & Column 9 & Column 10 & Column 11 \\
    \hline
    Row 2 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 3 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 4 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Row 6 & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \egroup
\end{sideways}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The second page appears because your table is too big. You have to reduce this somehow. Your problem was addressed several times before. Please read [Vertical alignment problem with \arraystretch and m column definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41203), [Make \addlinespace globally to work with all tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89123), and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50337.

Maybe you would be better served with a `tabu` or `tabularx` here. The latter would make your `\setlength\tabcolsep` unnecessary.

I would do the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \footnotesize % smaller font in order to fit the table on the page
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{6.4pt} % this is the maximum in order to fit on the page
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{tabular}{*{11}{l}}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 & Column 9 & Column 10 & Column 11 \\\addlinespace[2pt]
        \midrule
        Row 2 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 3 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 4 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 6 & & & & & & & & & & \\\addlinespace[2pt]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A `tabu` solution could be:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \tabulinesep = 3mm
    \footnotesize % smaller font in order to fit the table on the page
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {*{11}{X@{}}}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 & Column 9 & Column 10 & Column 11 \\
        \midrule
        Row 2 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 3 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 4 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        Row 6 & & & & & & & & & & \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```